# Nikon D750 And Pixel TW282TX

Tags: remote, nikon-d750

I have a problem with my remote shutter release (TW282TX) every time that I plug it in to my D750 it starts interval shooting by itself regardless of the mode I am on (looks like it's shooting a few pictures with intervals then waits and repeats it indefinitely) regardless of the mode I'm on and even if the channels are difference between the receiver and the remote. All the interval shooting things on my camera are off... Is it a problem with the item I bought and need to replace it or is it a setting I'm missing?

Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you connect the cable directly to the controller (i.e., use it wired, skipping the receiver)?

Comment: I didn't find a way to do it.. didn't see it in the manual as well

Comment: Isn't there a 1/8" TRS jack on the top of the handheld remote control? Plug the cable into the controller, and the other end into the camera...

Comment: Does the behavior your camera exhibits when you plug in the receiver the same as what happens when you hold down the camera's shutter button for a long time?

Comment: @MichaelC nope when i hold the shutter button on my camera down for a long time it just does nothing and when i release it i see the pic i took (one pic)

Comment: @scottbb i don't think so all i see is something round which i can't open it and i also don't see anything like that in the manual so maybe it's the 283 u mean?

Comment: No, the 283 is not what I'm referring to. I used to use the original [Vello Shutterboss](http://www.vellogear.com/product/6437/Vello-RCW_N1-Wireless-ShutterBoss-Timer-Remote-(Nikon-10_Pin-Connection)). The Pixel looks to be identical to the Vello. Perhaps it's a white label version of the Vello (or perhaps they're both white labels of something else)? There's a 1/8" TRS jack at the top of the controller, and I assume from [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiN3t.jpg) that the Pixel also has it.

Comment: Also, [p.9 of the manual](https://fccid.io/X5SWTCTW-282TX/User-Manual/User-Manual-Jan-06-1402679) labels **#1** as "Output Control Socket". That's what I'm referring to.

Comment: @scottbb i see what u mean but no matter how much i try i can't open it :| im afraid to break it...

Comment: @scottbb holy crap! i got it out... will answer ur question soon :)

Comment: @scottbb ok looks like it's fine with the cable connected directly to the remote... so the receiver is screwed? :(

Comment: sounds like it. =(

Comment: well thanks anyway for pushing me to try harder and open that damn connector though :D

Comment: If the receiver is set to channel [--], any 2.4GHz source nearby could be constantly triggering it. Did you try setting both the transmitter and receiver to one of the digital authentication channels?

Answer (score 1):

After some attempts with the help of the folks here we came to a conclusion that it's not settings in the camera or the remote and I'll probably going to use my warranty and see what the store says. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, you've indicated the transmit unit works fine connected directly to the camera.

It could be that the receiver is defective. Before sending it back, however, I'd try setting a different channel on the transmitter and receiver.

Be sure you have the transmitter and receiver set to the same "channel." Both are shipped set to the default "no channel" setting and the channel indicators on both units will will display [--] (two dashes minus the brackets). If a channel is set, it will display as a two digit number such as [08] or [72] (minus the brackets).

Apparently the transmissions have digital authentication so that more than one TW-282 set of may be used in the same area without interfering with one another. From the description at amazon: "The remote control can be set to any one of the 99 channels in order to avoid any interference from any other photographers that may be working with the same remote control around you."

From page 16 of the [user manual](https://fccid.io/X5SWTCTW-282TX/User-Manual/User-Manual-Jan-06-1402679), it states that [--] is the default channel setting on the receiver. It also says that if [--] is left as the channel setting on the remote, any TW-282 transmitter operating on any of the channels can control the receiver. That might also make it possible that any other 2.4GHz transmissions in the area may also constantly trigger the remote. Many wireless devices us the microwave 2.4GHz band. Microwave ovens may also interfere with the 2.4GHz band if they are in close proximity.

Before sending the receiver back as defective, try setting the transmitter and receiver to one of the 99 available encoded channels rather than the default [--]. You might need to try several different ones to find one that isn't affected by interference in the location you are at.